# # STOP-PRESS - This is a GAWK issue # How do I get Windows 10 to get CodePages to correctly display?

Tags: windows, awk, cmd, internationalization, codepages

How do I get Windows 10 to get CodePages to correctly display?

## STOP PRESS

**More investigation (creating echo of x80-ff) shows Windows is fine, it's a GAWK print (or terminal/driver) issue**
As shown in following screenshot of GAWK then ECHO of CP737 ...

[image: gawk then echo off x80-FF]

There are some non-ASCII and non-English characters that I want that are available in different Windows Codepages, but they don't display properly in Windows 10 CMD windows (Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.590]). The font used is Courier New (16pt). NB Code used is faulty but PoC is correct

The displayed blocks 80-FF almost (but not quite) duplicate CP1252 except from CP737 which is surprising bare, and shows the substitution char '?' for most positions.

What magic do I invoke to make the code pages more closely resemble what they should be? For reference I've been looking at [Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) and similar.

[image: CodePage 437]
[image: CodePage 737]
[image: CodePage 850]
[image: CodePage 860]
[image: CodePage 869]
[image: CodePage 1252]

The code to generate the character blocks is from gawk:

```
# gawk -f HiAscii.awk
BEGIN {
 #SEP = "><" # insert " SEP " into strings
 print "   <0123456789ABCEF>" #yeah, D is missing, but principle okay
 for(hi = 0x80; hi < 0x100; hi += 0x10){
  line = sprintf("%X <", hi)
  for(lo = 0x01; lo < 0x10; ++lo){ #yeah, these limits are wrong but screenshots already done
   line = line sprintf("%c%s", hi + lo, "")
  }
  print line 
 }
 print "   <0123456789ABCEF>" # yeah D missing
 print
 exit
}
```

and the batch file to run is

```
@ver
@echo "437 = DOS Latin US"
@chcp 437
@gawk -f HiAscii.awk
@echo "737 = DOS Greek"
@chcp 737
@gawk -f HiAscii.awk
@echo "850 = DOS Latin 1"
@chcp 850
@gawk -f HiAscii.awk
@echo "860 = DOS Portugese"
@chcp 860
@gawk -f HiAscii.awk
@echo "869 = DOS Greek2"
@chcp 869
@gawk -f HiAscii.awk
@echo "1252 = Super ISO8859-1"
@chcp 1252
@gawk -f HiAscii.awk
```

Comment: did you try with other font on the terminal. Limitation of this kind is generally there.

Comment: @neronLeVelu I displayed the x80-xff characters with Courier New (16pt), both via GAWK terminal driver (mainly '?') and CMD ECHO (perfect) so font not an issue - screenshot added at top of post just a few hours before your reply. But GAWK terminal driver definitely looking suspect.